# C: Use scanf() function instead of gets

Tags: c, string, shell

```
/* hexadecimal to decimal conversion */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
 char hex[17];
 long long decimal;
 int i , val, len;
 decimal = 0;


 // Input hexadecimal number from user

 printf("Enter any hexadecimal number: ");
 gets(hex);
 //Find the length of total number of hex digit
 len = strlen(hex);
 len--;

 for(i=0; hex[i]!='\0'; i++)
 {
 // Find the decimal representation of hex[i]
 if(hex[i]>='0' && hex[i]<='9')
 {
  val = hex[i] - 48;
 }
 else if(hex[i]>='a' && hex[i]<='f')
 {
  val = hex[i] - 97 + 10;
 }
 else if(hex[i]>='A' && hex[i]<='F')
 {
  val = hex[i] - 65 + 10;
 }
 decimal += val * pow(16, len);
 len--;
 }
 printf("Hexadecimal number = %s\n", hex);
 printf("Decimal number = %lld", decimal);
 return 0;
}
```

In the above program when i have used scanf instead of gets,it doesn't give the result.why? i used `scanf("%x",hex);`  . please explain me  `decimal += val * pow(16, len);` too.thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Unless this is a homework assignment, I would suggest using `strtoull`, and replacing `gets` with `fgets` since it can prevent a buffer overflow.

Comment: Curious coding style: Why was code using `'0'` in one place and `48` in another?  I'd expect `if(hex[i]>='0' ...)  { val = hex[i] - '0';` or its weaker cousin `if(hex[i]>=48 ...)  { val = hex[i] - 48;`, but not a mix of the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if you use `scanf()`, it does the conversion from string for you, that's sort of its entire point.

```
unsigned int x;
if(scanf("%x", &x) == 1)
  printf("you entered %d (hex 0x%x)\n", x, x);
```

You can't combine `%x` a pointer to a character array, it requires a pointer to an unsigned integer. This is of course well documented in the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf).

Also, using `pow()` here seems excessive, just multiply what you have by 16 *before* adding in each new digit:

```
unsigned int parsehex(const char *s)
{
  unsigned int x = 0;
  const char *digits = "0123456789abcdef";
  const char *p;
  while(*s && (p = strchr(digits, tolower(*s++))) != NULL)
  {
    x *= 16;
    x += (unsigned int) (p - digits);
  }
  return x;
}
```

This is a bit "heavier" (uses `strchr()`) than your code, but shorter and perhaps therefore easier to validate. If it's overly performance-critical, I'd consider looking into it.

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%x",hex);
```

should be

```
scanf("%s",hex);
```

you cannot do hex[i] when you read as integer.

```
decimal += val * pow(16, len); represents decimal = decimal + (val * pow(16, len));
```

Hopes this answers your question

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%x"...)` performs the conversion to integer for you.  Therefore, you want to deposit the result in `decimal`:

```
scanf("%x", &decimal);
```

Each iteration of the for loop is generating a nibble (4 bits) of the number into `val`.  The `val * pow(16, len);` is (in)effectively shifting the nibble into the correct position.  However, this code is using floating point math to accomplish this (`pow` returns a `double`) instead of simply left shifting by `4*len`.  A better approach is to simply shift `decimal` left by 4 bits on each iteration and add (or OR) the nibble into the least significant bits.  In this way, the first nibble will ultimately end up where it is supposed to be.

Also, character literals work as numbers, so instead of subtracting `48, 97, 65` it would read better if you subtracted `'0', 'f', 'F'` respectively.